# package object and scala worksheet

Tags: eclipse, scala

I have a strange behaviour in the eclipse IDE.

I reproduced it with the documentation on [package objects](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html)

- I have a file `src/main/scala/gardening/fruits/Fruit.scala` containing

  package gardening.fruits

  case class Fruit(name:String)

  object apple extends Fruit("Apple")

  object plum extends Fruit("Plum")
- a file `src/main/scala/gardening/fruits/package.scala` containing

  package gardening

  package object fruits {
    val planted = List(apple, plum)
    def showFruit(fruit: Fruit) {
      println(fruit.name +"s are ")
    }
  }
- a scala worksheet in `src/main/scala/fruitws.sc` containing

  import gardening.fruits._

  object PrintPlanted {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      for (fruit: Fruit <- fruits.planted) {
        showFruit(fruit)
      }
    }
  }

Now :

- eclipse says "can't find gardening" (and of course `fruits` and `Fruit`)
- if I hit `ctrl space` after placing a dot after gardening, some autocompletion appears though
- stranger, one of those completion is called gardeningfruits (so as a child of gardening, with no dots...)

What am I doing wrong that prevents the worksheet to execute properly ?

**edit**

I think the package object idea is not available in worksheet.

As a separate point, worksheet might mandate some file organisation on disk that scala files themselves escape (aka, having a file in gardening/fruit/fruit.scala and package gardening only in the file). Not sure..

Comment: Well, I think this is just a bug. I have experienced something similar myself, though I can't remember if it was related to package objects. I suggest using the REPL instead, it is more reliable.

Comment: good to know, I'll just go on then, and test some other things.

Answer (score 4):

You need to compile `.scala` files before you can import them into worksheet

Comment: Once you think about it, it makes perfect sense.